# How to display an message when user want to save a file in root of C Drive in java

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I have used JFileChooser to save a file in my Application.I have observed that the JFileChooser doesn't the files in root of "C Drive" without any notification. So, I want to display an Message to user whenever user want to save an file in root of "C Drive".How can I know the user selected directory is Root of "C Drive".Please help me.Thank you.

Comment: See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.getSelectedFile()` or `.getSelectedFiles()` methods to get the files that are selected. from the files you can fetch the file path using `.getPath()` this returns the file path as a String now you can apply conditions which will let you know if the selected file is in C:/ drive

This approach works even if the user selects just the directory also. In that case you have to use `.getCurrentDirectory()`, this returns the directory in which the user is currently in.

Little code snippet:

```
JFileChooser myFileChooser = new JFileChooser();

if(myFileChooser.getCurrentDirectory().getPath().equals("C:/")){
   System.out.println("saving file here is not allowed");
}
```

Comment: This is Working when I replace "c:/" with "c:\\"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JFileChooser#getSelectedFile` or `JFileChooser#getSelectedFiles` to get the selected `File`, you could then compare this with `File.listRoots` to determine if the selected file(s) is a root path, something like...

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
fc.showOpenDialog(null);
File selected = fc.getSelectedFile();
for (File f : File.listRoots()) {
    if (selected.equals(f)) {
        System.out.println("Is root path");
    }
}
```

for example.

Comment: Nice approach, I have a doubt in this, should the for loop have File.listRoots() or selected.listRoots() ? and why are we checking it for every selected file checking it for just one will do right? as we will not be able to select multiple files from different directories simultaneously I guess. (Just an instinct :|)

Comment: @VamshiAlladi File.listRoots and seletedFile.listToora is the same thing, seems as listRoots is a static method. This example is only checking against a single file, as you say, it'd be hard to select more non-root directories. This is also cross platform and doesn't assume what a root file actual is

Comment: Anyone want to highlight the reason for the downvote? Or should we just guess at you're reasoning and not learn anything?